# Blender image sequence (png) to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, export, png, blender

I'm new here and I would like to ask you guys a question about exporting Blender stuff into Unity. I've created a character in Blender and exported it to Unity. The thing is, when I export the character and its materials, when comes to exporting the face expressions, which is animated by an image sequence, on the animations preview I can only see the first offset of the image sequence. In Blender it was all set correctly so that every image was performed at the correct time of the animation. Could you explain the steps to export an image sequence into Unity from Blender?
Thanks a lot in advance.